# React Native: Opening URLs in Android (Equivalent to LinkingIOS.openURL)

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm aware that when using React Native to develop for iOS, I have access to the LinkingIOS and WebView modules to work with URLs. Is there any sort of equivalent for Android? All I'm looking to do is open the URL in the device's browser.

I know that the contributors are working on implementing WebView in Android:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/known-issues.html#views
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2701

But is there anything I can use in the meantime?

Again, All I need is an equivalent to `LinkingIOS.openUrl(url)` for Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the latest release of React Native (0.21), they provide module **[Linking](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html#content)** to handle incoming as well as outgoing web url.

This can work both on Android and iOS without platform specific.

Answer (score 3):

Try this module https://github.com/ivanph/react-native-webintent for opening urls in the default browser.

Comment: While I don't enjoy having to add a library for this, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is IntentAndroid to open URL.

Example

```
IntentAndroid.openURL(url)
```

Please refer to official doc for more info
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/intentandroid.html#content